# Hide the parent element if the child value matches certain string JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a table I have a `<td>` whose html is either **True** or **False**. If the value is **False** then hide the **parent**.

HTML :

```
<tr>
  <td class="IsRequired" align="left" valign="middle" style="width:3px;">False</td>
</tr>
```

Query :

```
$('.IsRequired').html("False").parent().hide();
```

This hides all the `<td>` whose class is "**IsRequired**"

Please advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("td.IsRequired:contains('False')").parent().hide();
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/95WLt/2/

Comment: Shouldn't that be `$(".IsRequired td:contains('False')")`? +1 anyhow

Comment: Not quite but close (the `td` isn't a descendent of the `IsRequired` element).  Updated my example

Comment: oh wow.  You are correct.  idk why I thought `.IsRequired` was the parent. o_o

Answer (score 2):

i think you should do

```
$('.IsRequired').each(function(){
           if($(this).html()=="False")
                $(this).parent().hide()
           });
```

Answer (score 2):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/93n42/

```
$('.IsRequired').filter(function(){
    return $(this).html() == "False"
}).parent().hide();
```

that should work.

Comment: Plus 1 for using filter instead of each, but I think the :contain pseudo-element approach has you beat!

Comment: why is filter preferred over .each ?

Comment: @Bogdan you know... I have no clue. o_o

Comment: The question is do you want to act on an entire collection that is filtered or do you want to act on each element of a collection individually? The nature of this question leads me to the former, but I admit it is largely a matter or preference.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.IsRequired').each(function(){
    if ( $(this).text() == 'False') $(this).parent().hide();
});
```